# Splitting a List Into Two Seperate Lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list:

```
result = [[67.0, 78.0], [132019.0, 242019.0]]
```

I am trying to completely split the list to make to separate lists:

```
x = [67.0, 78.]
y = [123019.0, 242019.0]
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can simply do `x, y = result`